AWS Neptune Serverless : cold start
Does AWS Neptune serverless goes through a cold start ? I am observing a slowness when lambda get a cold start. Is there a relation.

Depending on your minimum NCU settings, a Serverless instance may evict  portions of buffer pool cache to bring the memory allocated back to what is dictated by the allocated NCUs (2GB per NCU).
With that, you may see a lower BufferCacheHitRatio metric (CloudWatch metric) as the Serverless instance takes on new queries and begins to fetch portions of the graph into buffer pool. This means that the engine is needing to fetch related triples/quads from storage as they are not currently in buffer pool cache. This behavior can appear like a "cold start" on a minimally scaled instance.
